# UserDomainMask - What replaces it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have downloaded some code which had previously worked for the coder, who was able to run ok on his App.

However when I try to use the code to save data to iPhone memory I get an Error Message stating `Use of unresolved Identifier UserDomainMask..`

I have tried using `NSUserDomiainMask` to replace it and that doesn't seem to solve the problem.
It seems that the coder may have been using a Beta version of `Xcode6` for his App.

Can anyone please tell me what should replace `UserDomainMask` in the code below?

here is code:

```
func documentsDirectory() -> string {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask, UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    return documentsFolderPath
}
```

Kind Regards.

Del

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSSearchPathDomainMask, UserDomainMask` is incorrect, it needs to be combined into one argument: `NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask`

`as` needs to be `as!` to downcast.

It is not necessary to have the prefixes: `NSSearchPathDirectory` and `NSSearchPathDomainMask` as they will be inferred from the argument types.

Instead of indexing with `[0]` it is safer to use `.first`'

Use:

> Swift 2.x

```
let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
```

Full method:

```
func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
    return documentsFolderPath
}
```

> Swift 3

```
func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    return documentsFolderPath!
}
```

Comment: Thanx Zaph for your reply.

Comment: Hey zaph, I'm confused what the `.first` refers to. I know it means the first element in a set, but why exactly are there multiple elements in `.UserDomainMask`? Is it safe to say you always want to save/search for files in the first element?

Comment: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns a `String` array so an element needs to be picked. In the case of `.documentDirectory` there is one so the first array element is selected.